# Can't execute Js script using Selenium+Python

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I have a few date inputs in UI and I've got a problem when trying to fill the date in it - after filling, and switching to the next input, the date erases. I've dicided to execute Js script, which will change the value of input and set the right date.

[image: http://prntscr.com/epv597]

[image]

So, I do this:

```
wd.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value\\.bind="data.object[\'construction_date\']"]').execute_script("'$('input').val('01.01.1991')")
```

And got the AttributeError on execution:

```
 AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'window'
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: I would suggest against this because no user is going to fill in a date using JS. You're going down a path that is not a user scenario. Can you share a link to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change elements' `value` with `JavaScriptExecutor` you might try:

```
element = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value\\.bind="data.object[\'construction_date\']"]')
wd.execute_script('arguments[0].value="01.01.1991";', element)
```

Comment: It worked with this construction:

 `element = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value\\.bind="data.object[\'construction_date\']"]')
        wd.execute_script('arguments[0].value="01.01.1991";', element)
        wd.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value\\.bind="data.object[\'construction_date\']"]').send_keys(new_house.build_date)`

Without executing send_keys() method after changing input value, it doesn't.